# iOS 8: Metadata for image with filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, alassetslibrary

I am reading image metadata (such as EXIF and XMP) from images using the `ALAssetsLibrary`:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    URL* refurl = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        NSLog(@"Metadata: %@", myasset.defaultRepresentation.metadata);
    }

    mAssetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [mAssetslibrary assetForURL:refurl
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:failureblock];
}
```

For images captured with the camera or other images from the gallery this works fine and all metadata is shown. But for images which are filtered (e.g. using the iOS photo filters) only very little metadata (basically image dimensions only) is returned.

Accessing the filtered image data returns the filtered image, so the image data is fine and only the metadata is missing:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
[rep getBytes:imageDataBytes fromOffset:0 length:imageDataSize error:nil];
```

How can I get the meta data of an image which has an iOS photo filter applied?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can't at the moment. It's one of the many bugs in iOS 8 in the Photo APIs.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Apple.